How to set caching headers on the response of a Firebase 2nd gen https callable function?
Is it possible to set caching headers on the response of a 2nd gen https callable function? Namely, the cache-control headers to tell the browser to keep it in cache for a while.
Here's my typical boilerplate for a https callable:
import { getErrorMessage } from "@repo/common";
import { logger } from "firebase-functions";
import { z } from "zod";
import { region } from "~/config.js";
import { onCall, HttpsError } from "firebase-functions/v2/https";

const schema = z.object({
  something: z.string(),
});

export const my_callable_function = onCall(
  {
    region,
  },
  async (event) => {
    try {
      const { something } = schema.parse(event.data);

      console.log(`Do something: ${something}`);
    } catch (err) {
      const message = getErrorMessage(err);
      logger.error(`Failed to get something: ${message}`);

      throw new HttpsError("internal", message, err);
    }
  }
);

These functions are only used internally to our Firebase application. I see that there is also onRequest that you can use in place of onCall, which gives the express request and response objects, but I would like to stick to onCall because it does the user auth is handled and the functions are not publicly accessible.

It's not possible, and has not changed since v1.  The SDKs take over all of the HTTP details.  Callables are meant to be used for remote procedure calls and should not be cached.  If you need to implement caching, use a normal HTTP function instead, and make sure both the client and server agree on the scheme.
See:

How to set Authorization header while calling "callable function" on Firebase
How to add http headers to Firebase HttpsCallable function's response


Thanks again Doug. Gemini seems to be hallucinating on this point.
